# using stepExecution in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use stepExecution to retain data in a Spring batch. However I am running into some issues when I attempt to use it in my code execution:

```
ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
```

stepExecution was not recognized when I tired this. I imported org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution and also tried:

```
ExecutionContext context = StepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
```

Here StepExecution was recognized but I get a "Cannot make static reference to non-static method" error. Is my project not set up right; what am I doing wrong here?

```
import TextFileReader;
import OracleService;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;


public class myTask implements Tasklet {

private List<String> sourceQueries;
private List<String> targetQueries;

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    ExecutionContext context = StepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();

    ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    stepContext.put("theListKey", sourceQueries);

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}

public List<String> getSourceQueries() {
    return sourceQueries;
}

public void setSourceQueries(List<String> sourceQueries) {
    this.sourceQueries = sourceQueries;
}

public List<String> getTargetQueries() {
    return targetQueries;
}

public void setTargetQueries(List<String> targetQueries) {
    this.targetQueries = targetQueries;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [BeforeStep](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/annotation/BeforeStep.html) annotation to get stepExecution from your step-scoped bean:

```
@BeforeStep
public void setStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExcecution = stepExecution;
}
```

Comment: It says this.stepExecution cannot be resolved. Maybe I'm not creating a step-scoped bean correctly or something?

Comment: Could you add full code of your class to the question description?

Comment: Okay I added it. Do I need to pass stepExecution through the execute method?

Comment: You can get your ExcecutionContext from chunkContext by calling
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getExecutionContext()

Answer (score 1):

A chunk oriented tasklet can directly access the StepExecution from the ChunkContext :

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    StepExecution stepExecution = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution();
    ...
}
```